# Как загрузить сцену, при этом не делая ее основной, но имея возможность взаимодействовать с ее объектами, скриптами?

Tags: c#, unity3d

У меня есть загрузочный экран(loading scene) и главный экран игры(main scnen). Игра начинается с загрузочного экрана. Можно ли как-то загрузить main scene в фоне и иметь возможность взаимодействовать с ее объектами и их компонентами, при этом не переходя на нее, а оставаясь на loading scene?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

На сколько я знаю, единственный способ взаимодействовать с обьектами с "другой сцены" это загрузить обьект в эту сцену, работать с ним, а потом не выгружая из памяти перейти на следующую сцену.

Для последнего используется `DontDestroyOnLoad`.

Answer (score 0):

А для чего вы это хотите сделать? Если для того, чтобы, например, выбрать оружие или транспорт для персонажа, можно сделать скрипт [PlayerPrefs](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/PlayerPrefs.html).

Для загрузочного экрана потребуется такой код:

```
[SerializeField] private int _sceneID; // Id сцены

[SerializeField] private Image _loadingCircle; // изображение, которое будет показывать загрузку
[SerializeField] private Text _text; // текст, в который будут печататься проценты загрузки

void Start()
{
    StartCoroutine(AsyncLoad());
}

IEnumerator AsyncLoad()
{
    AsyncOperation op = SceneManager.LoadSceneAsync(_sceneID);
    while (!op.isDone)
    {
        float progress = op.progress / 0.9f;
        _loadingCircle.fillAmount = progress;
        _text.text = string.Format("{0:0}%", progress * 100);
        yield return null;
    }
}
```

Не забудьте вверху написать

```
  using UnityEngine.UI;
  using UnityEngine.SceneManagement;
```

Создайте отдельный Canvas, в котором будет изображение(например, круг), а также пустое текстовое поле. Далее повесьте скрипт и настройте его. не забудьте отключить его и включать при нажатии кнопок в главном меню.

Comment: Ну скажем хочу сделать генерацию карты, во время того как открыт загрузочный экран, а потом перейти на карту, тоесть на загруженную сцену